# SQL Server: How can I use the COUNT clause without GROUPing?

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I'm looking get two things from a query, given a set of contraints:

- The first match
- The total number of matches

I can get the first match by:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    ID,
    ReportYear,
    Name,
    SignDate,
     ... 
FROM Table
WHERE
     ...
ORDER BY ... //I can put in here which one I want to take
```

And then I can get the match count if I use

```
SELECT
    MIN(ID),
    MIN(ReportYear),
    MIN(Name),
    MIN(SignDate),
     ... ,
    COUNT(*) as MatchCount
FROM Table
WHERE
     ...
GROUP BY
     ??? // I don't really want any grouping
```

I really want to avoid both grouping and using an aggregate function on all my results. This question [SQL Server Select COUNT without using aggregate function or group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368967/sql-server-select-count-without-using-aggregate-function-or-group-by) suggests the answer would be

```
SELECT TOP 1
    ID,
    ReportYear,
    Name,
    SignDate,
     ... ,
    @@ROWCOUNT as MatchCount
FROM Table
```

This works without the TOP 1, but when it's in there, @@ROWCOUNT = number of rows returned, which is 1. How can I get essentially the output of COUNT(*) (whatever's left after the where clause) without any grouping or need to aggregate all the columns?

What I don't want to do is repeat each of these twice, once for the first row and then again for the @@ROWCOUNT. I'm not finding a way I can properly use GROUP BY, because I strictly want the number of items that match my criteria, and I want columns that if I GROUPed them would throw this number off - unless I'm misunderstanding GROUP BY.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are using a newish version of SQL Server (2008+ from memory) then you can use analytic functions.

Simplifying things somewhat, they are a way of way of doing an aggregate over a set of data instead of a group - an extension on basic aggregates.

Instead of this:

> ```
> SELECT
>      ... , 
>     COUNT(*) as MatchCount
> FROM Table
> WHERE
>      ...
> ```

You do this:

> ```
> SELECT
>      ... ,
>     COUNT(*) as MatchCount OVER (PARTITION BY <group fields> ORDER BY <order fields> )
> FROM Table
> WHERE
>      ...
> GROUP BY
> ```

Without actually running some code, I can't recall exactly which aggregates that you can't use in this fashion. Count is fine though.

Comment: So can I use it without PARTITIONing or ORDERing? Or somehow put something in the PARTITION BY <> that doesn't change the results (doesn't really group)?

Comment: Well the point of the partition is to group the data.  But group it withing a single record.   Withing grouping  (partition by) and/or sorting you just have a standard agregate anyway.

For the MS documentation look here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx
For your first example you can get the first record in a group, for which you sort appropriately, and return the first record.  (ie same as doing a "top 1" with an "order by").  What you can't do is use the GROUP clause (if you want to do that as well you need to use a sub query).

Comment: Your example worked perfectly as I wanted when combined with @Tom's answer of an empty OVER - COUNT(*) as MatchCount OVER () FROM ...

Comment: This COUNT and PARTITION combo worked well for what I needed on sql server 2005 also - I used it for COUNT and SUM.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can use OVER clause, which is an window function.

```
SELECT  TOP (1)
    OrderID, CustID, EmpID,
    COUNT(*) OVER() AS MatchCount
FROM    Sales.Orders
WHERE   OrderID % 2 = 1
ORDER BY OrderID DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try next query:

```
select top 1
    *, count(*) over () rowsCount
from
    (
        select
            *, dense_rank() over (order by ValueForOrder) n
        from
            myTable
    ) t
where
    n = 1
```