# How to speed up a COUNT of values grouped across an INNER JOIN of three large tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join

Could someone point me toward general principals for speeding up my query below?

I have a working query which aggregates a count of "property" values grouped across five columns.  But it takes over twenty minutes to run.

The count is aggregated across three related "Case" data tables which each have about 500,000 rows, and they are linked using a "UserID" plus "CaseNumber" composite key. (CaseNumbers are only unique per user.) I am using SQL Server 2005.

**My key problems seem to be:**

1. I need to "Group" *after* joining the three tables because each uniquely contains at least one of the columns that I am grouping against (so recommendations discussed [here](https://periscope.io/blog/use-subqueries-to-count-distinct-50x-faster.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444333/sql-server-how-can-i-use-the-count-clause-without-grouping) don't seem to apply).
2. My range of possible permutations in my desired result set (the product of the five column ranges) is large (~200,000 possibilities).

I am able to get results an order of magnitude more quickly if I limit my "range".  So I could, for example, redesign this query as a "foreach" loop that retrieves one month at a time.  But I would prefer to design a set-based approach.

I created a similar version of this query without the temp table, and another version with small temp tables for each "range" value, and the resulting speeds were similarly slow.

Ultimately, I want to get a count of the total number of permutations of "Categories" times "Properties" across every "Case" in the database, Grouped by Month and User.  Each "UserID" + "CaseNumber" is uniquely tied to one Month and Year, and may be tied to two or three "Categories" or "Properties", in which case I would like to count every permutation of Properties * Categories.

**The result set would look something like this:**

[image: Result Set]

**Primary Keys:**

- "CaseMaster" has a composite primary key against "UserID" and
  "CaseNumber".
- "CaseCategory" has a composite primary key against
  "UserID" and "CaseNumber" and "CategoryID".
- "CaseProperty" has a
  composite primary key against "UserID" and "CaseNumber" and "OtherID"
  (not PropertyID).
- "CaseNumber" is "varchar".  The rest are "char".

**Here is my draft query:**

```
USE MyDB

-- Drop Temp Table if it Exists
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DataRange') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #DataRange

SELECT [UserID]
    ,[Year]
    ,[Month]
    ,[CategoryID]
INTO #DataRange
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[IndexTable]

-- Aggregate a COUNT of "property" values joined across three large "Case" tables.
SELECT range.[UserID] AS [UserID]
    ,range.[Year] AS [Year]
    ,range.[Month] AS [Month]
    ,range.[CategoryID]
    ,cp.[PropertyID]
    ,COUNT(cp.[PropertyID]) AS [PropertyCount]

FROM
(
    -- (1) Get the range of possible permutations.
    (SELECT [UserID]
        ,[Year]
        ,[Month]
        ,[CategoryID]
    FROM #DataRange) range

    -- (2) Join against Dates AND Categories in the "Case Master" AND "Case Category" tables.
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT cm.[CaseNumber] AS [CaseNumber]
               ,cm.[UserID] AS [UserID]
               ,cm.[Year] AS [Year]
               ,cm.[Month] AS [Month]
               ,cc.[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID]
        FROM
            ((SELECT [CaseNumber]
                     ,[UserID]
                     ,(CASE WHEN value1 = 'A' THEN datepart(year, date1)
                       ELSE datepart(year, date2) END) AS Year,
                     ,(CASE WHEN value2 = 'B' THEN datepart(month, date1)
                       ELSE datepart(month, date2) END) AS Month     
            FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[CaseMaster]) cm

            INNER JOIN

            (SELECT [CaseNumber]
                   ,[UserID]
                   ,[CategoryID]
            FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[CaseCategory]) cc

            ON cm.UserID = cc.UserID AND cm.CaseNumber = cc.CaseNumber)

    ) case

    ON range.[UserID] = case.[UserID] AND range.[Year] = case.[IncYear]
        AND range.[Month] = case.[IncMonth] AND range.[WebCategoryID] = case.[WebCategoryID]


    -- (3) Join against a "Property" fields in the "Case Property" table.
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT [CaseNumber]
           ,[UserID]
           ,[property1] AS [PropertyID]
        FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[CaseProperty]
    ) cp

    ON range.UserID = cp.UserID AND case.CaseNumber = cp.CaseNumber
    AND cp.[PropertyID] IN (SELECT [PropertyID] FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[PropertyTypes])

)
GROUP BY range.[UserID], range.[Year], range.[Month], range.[CategoryID], p.[PropertyID]

DROP TABLE #DataRange

GO
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and describe what you want to do?  Sample data and desired results are helpful.

Comment: What is the purpose of the temp table? You only refer to it once. It is not a subset of the IndexTable. There's not filtering or other limiting of the number of rows. Whatever indexes are on the main table are of no use.

Comment: There's seem to be a bunch of dangling aliases in the middle. What's `i` and `data`?

Comment: I've corrected typos in the aliasing and added an example result set.

Comment: The temp table is not strictly necessary, but during testing I am using it to do test queries against smaller "range" sets.  (Ex: Querying a month worth of data is much more than twelve times as fast as querying a year.)

Comment: Indexing will play a big part in this. Can you describe in detail what indexes are currently defined?

Comment: Cardinality, too. How "unique" are the contents of the various columns? How many rows are there in each table? How much of the table is likely to be queried/returned in each call?

Comment: I've added a description of the table primary keys.  Each "Case" data table has about 500,000 rows.  Each unique "UserID" + "CaseNumber" combination in the "Master" table ties to a few, or sometimes zero, "Category" and "Property" records.  Some users have no data in some months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indices. Check the query plan for all necessary indices.

If the are in place, it is too slow and you need this t o be faster, find the bottleneck and buy the proper hardware to fix it, OR find another way o get the data (caching in memory etc.) though I think that wont work for this query.

So, at one point there is a reason large data analysis needs expensive hardware to hit it. Smae reason I am just plugging 5tb SSD into my database server.

That said, you likely have a throughput bottleneck on tempdb - and that loves a nice Raid 0 of SSD ;)

Comment: The since-posted indexes look ok. If non-clustered (default settings can be overridden), consider making them clustered.

Answer (score 1):

Given some assumptions:

- The query hits (aggregates) across virtually every row in every table, and
- The tables are truly large (joins over three tables with 500k rows in each qualify), and
- The query gets run frequently OR if the query has to run quickly when it is called

Then you might be looking at a data warehouse (datamart, reporting table) situation. Some of the basic concepts behind this are:

- Design the tables to support reporting (olap) queries, not writing/update (oltp) queries
- At designated points in time (daily? hourly?) you refresh the warehouse, loading in all data that has been added to the system since the last refresh. (Or, reload everything from scratch each time, but that is not ideal)
- Designed properly, reporting queries could run very quickly

In cases where you are just processing too much data, queries like this simply cannot be run quickly—think “end of the day” report, or something run overnight. The advantage of the warehouse here is that these long-running queries will not be running on the regular transaction, so you don’t get locking, blocking, or deadlock situations (so long as you’re not running the queries at the same time you’re trying to load the tables.) In addition, the underlying data won’t change while the query is being run.

Comment: Your first two assumptions are true.  As far as frequency, I am just planning to run this nightly or to refresh data as needed.  I'm using this query to populate a reporting table for a website.  But I need to make ten other queries like this for similar reports, and I'm worried that a half hour (or more) each is still too slow, even for a nightly process.

Comment: I'd say if you have a half-hour process, overnight is the ideal time to run them. That's when we do ours.

Comment: I totally agree.  But if my set of processes takes six or eight hours, that would have negative impact.  If there are any optimizations that could even speed me up by a factor of five or ten, that would be a huge benefit.  And I'm also concerned that I may need to design processes that INNER JOIN _four_ large tables.

Comment: Even more reason to consider a warehouse/reporting solution. It might take hours to load all the data into the tables, but--properly designed (no one would say its easy)--it would take minutes to add the most recent day's worth of activity to the set. Reading one big Fact table will be faster than a four-way join across four big ones.

Comment: I'll think more about that. In theory all of the data could be updated, including prior years, so detecting changes to the total counts (including deletes) would involve significant changes to how we currently track our updates.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing does appear to have been the culprit, specifically the order of elements in my composite primary key in the "Case Property" table.

For some reason the "Case Property" table was originally created (not by me!) with the key elements in the order "UserID" -> "OtherID" -> "CaseNumber" instead of "UserID" -> "CaseNumber" -> "OtherID".

Switching the order, with no other changes, sped up my query from 16 minutes to 1 second for the same range set.

Alternatively, adding the following trivial "ON" clause after the "Case Property" INNER JOIN, also sped up the query from 16 minutes to 11 seconds, without the key correction, even though this clause has no impact on the result set and simply searches over the range of all possible values.

```
AND cp.[OtherID] IN (SELECT [OtherID] FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[OtherIDLookupTable])
```

Thank you TomTom and Philip for the helpful suggestions and insights!